# PropertyReferenceException in spring data mongodb 2.1.0

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring data mongodb 2.1.0.
And have custom implementation of repository as given below:

```
public class ProductItemRepositoryImpl implements ProductItemRepositoryCustom {


  @Override
  public List<String> getItemIdsGivenSkuOrCode(String itemIdType, String itemId) {
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(itemIdType).is(itemId));
    return mongoTemplate
        .findDistinct(query, FieldNames.PRODUCT_ITEM_ID, ProductItem.COLLECTION_NAME,
            String.class);
  }
}
```

Custom repo :

```
public interface ProductItemRepositoryCustom {
  List<String> getItemIdsGivenSkuOrCode(String itemIdType, String itemId);
}
```

Repo :

```
public interface ProductItemRepository
    extends MongoRepository<ProductItem, Long>, ProductItemRepositoryCustom {
}
```

I dont understand why it is considering custom method(getItemIdsGivenSkuOrCode) as property.
When i am running this, getting below given error :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productItemRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property getItemIdsGivenSku found for type ProductItem!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:740) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do something with method naming

Assuming your fields in `ProductItem` are

```
String itemIdType;
String itemId;
```

Method Name would be

```
public interface ProductItemRepositoryCustom {
  List<String> findByItemIdTypeOrItemId(String itemIdType, String itemId);
}
```

or to be on safer side you can add query

```
@Query("{ 'itemIdType': ?0, 'itemId': ?1}")
public List<String> findByItemIdTypeOrItemId(String itemIdType, String itemId);
```

Comment: I don't think there is any restriction on method name in custom repository.

Comment: In that case, was just wondering how will MongoRepository know how to form the query.  Pls have a look at this https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html    Scroll down to   6.3 Query methods

Comment: Thanks for your response. By default it uses postfix "impl". And it generates query for repository interface methods, not for custom repo methods(We need to provide implementation for these custom methods).

Comment: Thanks. I guess implementation code wasn't added when I read the question. Missed it.

Comment: No problem. Thanks.